# Same row different column. Excel Formula

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, excel-indirect

If is possible with the if(indirect formula to give me the value from the same row but from a different column if a specific cell is from that row?

More specific: I want cell =Sheet2!F23 to give me =Sheet1!N11 if =sheet2!C23 is from Sheet1!B11.
The important thing is the I need it to come from row 11 but from a different column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you make it bit clearer? by virtue of a good example

Comment: I figured it out. 
Just gave the rows an unique number and used a =IFERROR(INDEX formula. Thanks though

Comment: Please add your answer. Someone else may have the same issue, we may point out inefficiencies and you will be able to accept an answer thus close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following:

On Sheet 1 i gave all the rows a unique number in column A
On sheet 2 i just put in the unique number(C23) and the rest of the cells on that row used the formula below with. The only thing i needed to change was the index of which column needed to be matched.
It might not be the most efficient way but i worked for me.

=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B;MATCH($C23;Sheet1!$A:$A;0));"")